# touchSwipe messes with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've got an input field with a Jquery datepicker for Twitter Bootstrap ([this one](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)) and in my application I also use touchSwipe ([this](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin)). For some reason the two don't work together. The following happens:
When I click inside the input field for the first time, the datepicker shows.
[image: the datepicker]

When I don't select a date (and click somewhere outside the textfield so the datepicker disappears), the second time I select the input field an option field appears. When I do select a date, the datepicker doesn't show a second time.

[image: option field]

I use the following JS:

```
// Enable touchSwipe
$(window).ready(function () {
    $('#form').swipe({
        swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            if($(window).width() < 751) {
            $('#daycalendar').animate({
                right: '0%'
            }, 250);
        } else { 
            // absolutely nothing 
        }
    },
    swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        if($(window).width() < 751) {
            $('#daycalendar').animate({
                right: '-80%'
            }, 250);
        } else { 
            // absolutely nothing 
        }
    },
    threshold: 0
});
});
// Call datepicker
$('#date').datepicker();
```

When I remove the touchSwipe JS import script or everything from the code above (except the last two lines) the datepicker works.

The datepicker works also when I first select a different input field and then click the date input field again.

I've plowed through both datepicker and touchSwipe JS files, but I can't find the element that screwing with datepicker.

Can somebody help?

**Edit** Here is a live version. It's only optimized for mobile yet so you might want to scale you're browser down (width).
http://paulvandendool.nl/lab/test/

Comment: try `$('#date').off('click').datepicker()` to unbind previous binding

Comment: Didn't help. Bummer :(

Comment: :( could you provide your HTML? even better a fiddle...

Comment: Added a live version in the original question. If you minimize the width of your browser it will look the best. A fiddle wasn't possible because of the external recourses used.

Comment: which device do you use? on desktop it's working fine

Comment: Didn't work on Chrome and Firefox on my iMac. It works the first time you click, but not the second time. But I noticed that the input field didn't un-focus when I clicked somewhere else. It only un-focussed when I selected an other input field. So I searched the github issues for 'focus' and found this: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/29. Adding the piece of code provided worked. Upvote for the effort. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed how the input field stayed focused even though I clicked outside of it. Adding the following code to the `swipe` function worked:

```
swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, fingerCount) {
    if ( phase == "move" || phase == "start" ) {
        var $target = event.target.nodeName;
        if( $target.toLowerCase() === 'input' ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $('input').blur();
        }
    }
},
```

https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/29

Comment: but you should update the plugin, apparently it's fixed. and I don't like the wild `$(input).blur()`, too broad